# how to get tinyMCE text without using id

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have a am working on project where i load a lot of tinyMCE editor instances dynamically. Do not have access to element id, because user has a possibility to add new editor instance.

Previously when I was using regular textfields, so I was looping through all of them and doing something like this:

```js
var obj = {
    $(this).find('.mytextfieldselector').val()
}
```

problem is, that when I try to find tiny mce like this:

```js
$(this).find('.mce-tinymce').getContent();
```

It doesn't work.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you missing the `$` in front of `(this)`?

Comment: Ahh sorry it's a typo in post, I wasn't copy pasting it.

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE maintains an array of all editor instances on a page via `tinymce.editors` - it returns an array.

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows how to use it to iterate over all the editors and collect their content:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/migaab/1

Answer (score 0):

Today I found a solution. It was much simpler than I thought.

Loop through all the divs you have. 
First take attribute 'id' of your editor using jquery. Then use `tinyMCE.get(id)`.

it would be something like this:

```
$(this).find('.yourDivSelector').each(function() {

var currentEditorId = $(this).find('.yourTinyMCEEditorSelector').attr('id');
var textAreaValue = tinyMCE.get(currentEditorId).getContent();

//Here do what you want wit textAreatValue

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent()
```